# How can I get my insertnode to stop being highlighted?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, select, range

I have a Javascript function for a chrome extension I am making that shows a popup dictionary. This is done by inserting a span node under the text the user has highlighted with their mouse.

```
function insertPopupDict() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        var text = selection.toString();
        var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);

        var popupDictionaryWindow = document.createElement('span');
        popupDictionaryWindow.id = 'hawaiian-popup-dictionary'
        popupDictionaryWindow.style = 'margin-top: 35px; width: 360px;background-color: #555;color: #fff;text-align: center;border-radius: 6px;padding: 8px 0;position: absolute;z-index: 1;';
        
        searchWord(text).then(defenitions => {
            popupDictionaryWindow.innerHTML = text + "<hr><br>";
            for (var i = 0; i < defenitions.length; i++) {
                popupDictionaryWindow.innerHTML += defenitions[i] + "<br><br>"
            }
            range.insertNode(popupDictionaryWindow);
        });
        popupVisible = true;
    }
}
```

The popup works, but the text in the popup span gets highlighted as well.

[image]

Does anybody know how to stop this from happening? I'm new to Javascript and honestly don't fully understand how the selection range works. I want to leave the selected word highlighted, but de-select anything in the new popup span.

Comment: since you're adding the element to the selected `range` of course the text will be selected - you'll need to re-think the popup text

Comment: @Bravo care to elaborate? Not sure what you mean by re-think.

Comment: Actually, not sure if this is accurate? I tried placing it way out of the way and the text is still highlighted.
https://i.imgur.com/3kXiAL5.png

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Still don't entirely understand why I had to do this, but the solution was to just create a new range at the same spot as the old one.

```
function insertPopupDict() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        let selection = window.getSelection();
        var text = selection.toString();
        var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);

        //this is the solution to the highlight problem
        var newRange = document.createRange();
        newRange.setStart(selection.focusNode, selection.startOffset);

        var popupDictionaryWindow = document.createElement('span');
        popupDictionaryWindow.id = 'hawaiian-popup-dictionary'
        popupDictionaryWindow.style = 'margin-top: 35px; width: 360px;background-color: #555;color: #fff;text-align: center;border-radius: 6px;padding: 8px 0;position: absolute;z-index: 1;';

        searchWord(text).then(defenitions => {
            popupDictionaryWindow.innerHTML = text + "<hr><br>";
            for (var i = 0; i < defenitions.length; i++) {
                popupDictionaryWindow.innerHTML += defenitions[i] + "<br><br>"
            }
            //place node at newRange instead of range
            newRange.insertNode(popupDictionaryWindow);
        });
        popupVisible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure you've noticed, but this does not position the popup the same way your original code does